# Java captureDeviceManager.getDevice returns no find any capture device on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, webcam, jmf

I want to capture a image from laptop's webcam.

The webcam works correctly when runs skype or any webcam application.

My workstation is ubuntu 11.10.

My webcam locate /dev/v4l and this path include by-id by-path.

```
   Vector deviceList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(new YUVFormat());
```

2 types of format of the webcam RGB and YUV.

i run v4l-info and i know format YUV.

returns No find capture device

Manually i added jmf.jar in reference libraries.

Please help me.

I just want to capture a image using java in ubuntu 11.10.

Can you recommend me any other methods if you can't find solutions for the problem above.

Thank you for any helping

Comment: any luck on getting this to work?